# Legend position in multiple plots layout in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, legend

I need to put the legend under the title of the image but I don't know how to do it easily

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3),oma=c(0,0,0,0),xpd=NA)
maximo<-max(valuetable[,-ncol(valuetable)],na.rm = T )
c1<-which(data$class==1);cluster1 <- data[c1,]
c2<-which(data$class==2);cluster2 <- data[c2,]
c3<-which(data$class==3);cluster3 <- data[c3,]
c4<-which(data$class==4);cluster4 <- data[c4,]
c5<-which(data$class==5);cluster5 <- data[c5,]
hist(as.matrix(cluster1[,-ncol(cluster1)]),ylab="Frecuencia",xlab="Precipitación (mm)",ylim=c(0,3000), xlim=c(0,maximo),col=Set1T[1],main="");box()
hist(as.matrix(cluster2[,-ncol(cluster2)]),ylab="Frecuencia",xlab="Precipitación (mm)",ylim=c(0,3000), xlim=c(0,maximo),col=Set1T[2],main="");box()
hist(as.matrix(cluster3[,-ncol(cluster3)]),ylab="Frecuencia",xlab="Precipitación (mm)",ylim=c(0,3000), xlim=c(0,maximo),col=Set1T[3],main="");box()
hist(as.matrix(cluster4[,-ncol(cluster4)]),ylab="Frecuencia",xlab="Precipitación (mm)",ylim=c(0,3000), xlim=c(0,maximo),col=Set1T[4],main="");box()
hist(as.matrix(cluster5[,-ncol(cluster5)]),ylab="Frecuencia",xlab="Precipitación (mm)",ylim=c(0,3000), xlim=c(0,maximo),col=Set1T[5],main="");box()
mtext("Histogramas de Precipitación", side = 3, line = -1.5, outer = TRUE)
legend("top",legend=c("Cluster 1", "Cluster 2","Cluster 3","Cluster 4","Cluster 5"),col = 1:5, lty=1,horiz = T,lwd=3, bty = "n", cex = 1.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of specifying "top" as the first parameter of `legend()`, put two numbers (the first for "x" position, the second for "y" position) as shown below. The first two parameters of `legend()` are x and y.

`legend(-0.5, 62, legend=c("Cluster 1", "Cluster 2","Cluster 3","Cluster 4","Cluster 5"),col = 1:5, lty=1,horiz = T,lwd=3, bty = "n", cex = 1.3)`

This produces the following results:
[image]

You'll probably just have to play with the numbers a bit to make it look nice.

---

The entire code to perfectly replicate the example plot is:

```
data(mtcars)
data <- mtcars

par(mfrow = c(2, 3), oma = c(0, 0, 3, 0), xpd = NA)

hist(mtcars$vs)
hist(mtcars$vs)
hist(mtcars$vs)
hist(mtcars$vs)
hist(mtcars$vs)

mtext("Histogramas de Precipitación", side = 3, outer = T)

legend (
    x = -0.5, y = 62, # these two parameters are the relevant ones
    legend = c("Cluster 1", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 3", "Cluster 4", "Cluster 5"),
    col = 1:5, 
    lty = 1,
    horiz = T,
    lwd = 3, 
    bty = "n",
    cex = 1.3
)
```

---

Edited because I initially misread the question.

Comment: Thanks your answer seems usefull, however I can't put the legend under the title modifying the x and y parameters. Can you put your entire code please to replicate it

Comment: Hey, I added the code to replicate my example to the original answer. Changing the values of "x" and "y" in the call to legend() should absolutely change the position of the legend on the plot if you run my example code. Hopefully that helps.